# Multi line cout

Tags: c++

Is there a way that you could do this piece of code with just one command, or to be better understood,  a kind of multi line cout? I ask because I was trying to make a menu using this but it looks sloppy when the menu loads up.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void setCursorPos(int, int);
//setCursorPos - Sets position of console cursor
//@param int - the new x position of the cursor
//@param int - the new y position of the cursor



SetConsoleTextAttribute( GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), 0x70);
int x, y;
x = 0;
y = 0;
while(y <= 24)
{
    while(x <= 79)
    {
        setCursorPos(x, y);
        cout << " ";
        x++;
    }
    x = 0;
    y++;
}

//Function
void setCursorPos(int x, int y)
{
    COORD Coord;

    Coord.X = x;
    Coord.Y = y;

    SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), Coord);
}
```

Comment: Instead of print space, move cursor, print space, move cursor, etc.. just print 80 spaces if that's what you want.

Comment: `std::iostream` is about line-based I/O, and very poorly equipped for the kind of "terminal GUI" you are imagining. You might want to take a look at [ncurses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses), which is purpose-built for this.

Comment: 'cout << endl' or 'cout < "\n"' will create a new line